How to add a Dialog for Role selection after Login using JWT Strategy in nextAuth
After Login (AzureADProvider) the user has to choose exactly one Role. It can happen over a Dialog. In the Claims (token) we have a list of Roles after authentication.
How can I achieve this?

Would you like to display a Dialog for role selection on browser side while user access protected resource/endpoint with access token?

this is the idea, I mean when the user has more than one Role in the token, he should has the possibility to select exactly one for the current session
